# Is there any way to delete/remove admin user programmatically?

Tags: admin

I wanted to delete an admin user programmatically, I have only FTP access.

Comment: when faced with issues like this, try to simulate the actions in the admin controller. If you take a look in `Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController::deleteAction()` you will find a code similar to what @SanderMangel posted as an answer.

Comment: While trying to delete an admin user, just be careful to not delete admin user id 0.

Comment: Hey Nived, can you post the error you've received on the BE?

Answer (score 3):

Although untested it stands to reason that you can use the normal Magento flow like with all models

```
Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load('user id')->delete();
```

But again, I didn't test it.

Comment: I tried the above code, not working, now I am not able to access admin, getting an error.

Comment: Please update your answer with the error thrown and also explain how you executed this code.

Comment: Confirmed, this method works. My code:

$model = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$user = $model->loadByUsername($username);
$user->delete();